# For given $a \in \mathbb{R}$ there exists unique continuous function $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$.

Tags: real-analysis, exponential-function, mathematical-modeling

> For given $a \in \mathbb{R}$ there exists unique continuous function $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ that satiafy $f(x+y)=f(x)f(y)$ for $x,y \in \mathbb{R}$ and $f(1)=a$.

These theorems were discussed in my mathematical-modeling class and were given to us to prove them.

Comment: Have you considered $a^x$?

Comment: If $f$ is monotone, it follows actually in exactly the same way as in the continuous case.